# java telnet socket : BufferedReader / BufferedWriter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, bufferedreader

My server opens a telnet port on 23999 and when I give `telnet localhost 23999`, it shows below :

```
< BP-SAS ==> bplin19 !>telnet 0 23999
Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.
Escape character is '^]'.
Please enter password to authenticate:
(here i give password for example abc123)   
Enter 'help' at any point to get a listing of all registered commands...
BAS> log set-info 1 ( commad i have entered and it does somthing )
```

Now Instead of open like this, I have to write java code which does this thing.

1. connect to host 23999 port
2. enter password
3. enter commad

> 

```
Socket soc=new Socket("192.168.9.7",23999);
  while(true){
  //create buffered writer
  BufferedReader bwin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(soc.getOutputStream()));
  BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(soc.getOutputStream()));
  String readFir = bwin.readLine();
  System.out.println(readFir);
        if(readFir.startsWith("Please")){
            System.out.println("Password Entered");
            bw.write("abc123");
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();  //close buffered Reader 
        }

        readFir = bwin.readLine();
        if(readFir.startsWith("Enter")){
            System.out.println("Enter command");
            bw1.write("log set-info 1");
            bw1.flush();
            bw1.close();  //close buffered Reader 
        }
        //readFir = bwin.readLine();
    }
```

This is not working.Actually, I am bit confused what approach I should follow.Very much confused between reader/writer.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried a single OutputStreamWriter? When you close the first BufferedWriter (bw) you're closing the socket output stream. Also when you execute this what is written to stdout?

Comment: @Jason -  SocketClosed Exception at readFir = bwin.readLine(); line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only need to get socket input stream and output stream once (do this outside the while loop). Try something like this:

```
Socket soc = new Socket("192.168.9.7",23999);
//create buffered writer
BufferedReader bwin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(soc.getOutputStream()));
while (true) {
        String readFir = bwin.readLine();
        if (readFir == nul) break;
        System.out.println(readFir);
        if(readFir.startsWith("Please")){
            System.out.println("Password Entered");
            bw.write("abc123");
            bw.newLine();
            // instead might have to explicitly write "\r\n"
            // depending platform you're connecting from.
            bw.flush();
        }
        else if(readFir.startsWith("Enter")){
            System.out.println("Enter command");
            bw.write("log set-info 1");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();  //close buffered Writer
            break;
        } else System.out.println("Skip: " + readFir);
  }
```

For accessing Telnet protocol you might be better off using a library such as [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) rather than do it yourself.

Comment: After Executing it I got : 
Please enter password to authenticate:
Password Entered 

(Its wait at this line readFir = bwin.readLine();)

Comment: For debugging add else to print any unexpected input.

Comment: Using your code, I have observered one more thing.My server is reading password like this...

reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
password = reader.readLine(); // here its hangs, it is not able to read the password.(if i do bw.write("abc123");        bw.flush();bw.close(); then it is able to read password...wondered why ?? )

Comment: Probably need newline entered after the password.

Comment: Yup...After adding newline..its running fine.I have two questions : 1) why newline is required. 2) In which cases bwin.readLine(); will return null.

Comment: If enter via command-line you enter the password followed by Enter key which itself is part of the input string. Readline() will return null when the input stream has no more to read.

Comment: Thanks JasonM1 for your time and effort !

Comment: the example from oracle does it with twice.