# Reboot modem with Java

Tags: java, telnet

I'm trying to make reboot modem application with java using telnet. But cmd stops when username must be entered.

```
private static void RebootModem()  throws IOException {

    String tel = "telnet 192.168.1.1 23";
    String user = "admin";
    String pass = "admin";
    String reboot = "reboot";
    String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /c" +tel+ "/c" +user+ "/c" +pass+"/c" +reboot;

    try
    {
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(child.getOutputStream(), true);
    }
    catch(IOException e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: [Print the command](https://ideone.com/LEfEWp), you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: seems like forgot some spaces here and there

Comment: I suggest you not using CMD, just use Sockets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894509/java-telnet-socket-bufferedreader-bufferedwriter

Comment: Besides that, it's not clear why you need `/c` after `/c start`

Answer (score 0):

And then execute this script

```
 Set cloner = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cloner.run"cmd"
WScript.Sleep 500

cloner.run"telnet 192.168.2.1"
WScript.Sleep 500

cloner.SendKeys"username"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

cloner.SendKeys"password"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

cloner.SendKeys"reboot"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
```

save as .vbs
In java
   Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K"+your_vbs_path);

Comment: Hi nyavuzcan, the OP requested a solution in Java. Could you edit your answer to use Java?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your comment